# Where is the host file located on OpenVMS systems?

Tags: hosts-file, openvms

[Hosts (file) entry on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) has a table listing the location name of the hosts file (which maps hostnames to IP addresses) on various systems. Where is this info stored on [OpenVMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS) systems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenVMS doesn't use a hosts file that can be directly edited. You have to use either the `TCPIP` or `UCX` (for pre v5 tcpip services) commands e.g.

```
$TCPIP
tcpip> SET HOST test.example.com /address=10.0.0.100
tcpip> SET HOST test.example.com /alias=somealian
```

Would create a host entry for a host called `test.example.com` with address `10.0.0.100` and an alias of `somealias`. As with most things OpenVMS the command's internal help is excellent.

It looks like the file that contains the actual entries is pointed to by the logical name TCPIP$HOST.

The Documentation can be found online [here](https://www.digiater.nl/openvms/doc/ia64-v8.3/network/tcpip56/6527/6527pro_contents.html).